# How to find a regular parameter system of the local ring $ \mathbb{C} [X_0, \dots, X_n]_{(P \ )} $?

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, commutative-algebra, local-rings, regular-rings

How to find a regular parameter system of the local ring : $ \mathbb{C} [X_0, \dots, X_n]_{(P \ )} $ with : $ (P \ ) $ a prime ideal of : $ \mathbb{C} [X_0, \dots, X_n] $ ( i.e : $ P \in \mathbb{C} [X_0, \dots, X_n] $ is an irreducible homogeneous polynomial ) ?

$ \mathbb{C} [X_0, \dots, X_n] $ is the ring of **homogeneous** polynomials in : $ X_0, \dots, X_n $.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Maybe try it for a real simple case, like $n=2$ and $P=X_0^2+X_1^2+X_2^2$ ? Or maybe, even simpler, $n=1$ and $P=X_0+X_1$.

Comment: The sum of two homogeneous polynomials is not homogeneous, so what ring are you talking about?